# How to manage absolute file path in visual studio project in source control?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control

I am hosting a source control git repo with a visual studio c++ project. It uses additional library directories and additional include directories in the .vcxproj file. I decided that I have two options:

> 1). Remove the .vcxproj file from source control, and only upload the files which contain source code.
>
> 2). Upload the .vcxproj file including my include and lib directories, and just live with the repo being polluted.

I noticed that there is a .vcxproj.user file which has specific user details, but I don't know if it's possible to store file paths there. I wonder if there is a way to store absolute file paths like the include and library directories in a file other than the .vcxproj file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.vcxproj` file is necessary for C++ project, so I suggest you **keep the `.vcproject` in source control and also move the libraries into your source code** (as the option2 you mentioned).

And it won't pollute your git repo since you can manage the files into a subfolder in your git repo and add references with the new paths.

> I noticed that there is a .vcxproj.user file which has specific user
>   details, but I don't know if it's possible to store file paths there.

The `.vcxproj.user` file is only for user specified information, and it shouldn't be added into git repo. You can ingore the file in `.gitginore`. And this is an example [`.gitignore`](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore) which suit for VS projects.

> I wonder if there is a way to store absolute file paths like the
>   include and library directories in a file other than the .vcxproj
>   file.

No, there is no way to store the files from outside of the git repo directory into git repo. Even you can use the references from library directories, but when someone clone your git repo into another machine, the references won't be found.

Besides, if you are willing to manage the libraries into a separate git repo, you can add the libraries as [git submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for your current repo.